# Задача по программированию

Tags: c++, массивы

Создать программу, которая определяет и инициализирует многомерный массив, а затем реализует следующие виды деятельности:

1. Преобразование исходного массива (все нечетные элементы должны быть удвоены). Кол-во строк 4, кол-во элементов 3
2. Создание и заполнение нового (одномерного) массива типа double. Массив должен быть наполнен квадратными корнями минимальных положительных элементов строк предыдущего трансформированного массива.

Что думаю я:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

int minPositive(int **array, const int, const int);

void main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
const int arrayRow = 4, arrayElements = 3;
int **array = new int*[arrayRow];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRow; i++) {
    array[i] = new int[arrayElements];
}
cout << "Введите элементы массива: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayElements; j++) {
        cout << i + 1 << "-я строка " << j + 1 << "-й столбец: ";
        cin >> array[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << "Массив матрицей 4х3: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRow; i++) {
     cout << " | ";
     for (int j = 0; j < arrayElements; j++) {
         cout << setw(4) << array[i][j] << "  ";
     }
     cout << " | " << endl;
}
cout << "Ищем нечетные числа в каждой строке и удваиваем: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRow; i++) {
     cout << " | ";
     for (int j = 0; j < arrayElements; j++) {
          if (array[i][j] % 2 != 0) {
              array[i][j] *= 2;
          }
          cout << setw(4) << array[i][j] << "  ";
     }
     cout << " | " << endl;
}
cout << endl;
double *sqrtArray = new double[arrayRow];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRow; i++) {
    delete[] array[i];
}
delete[] array;
delete[] sqrtArray;
system("pause");
}

int minPositive(int **array, const int arrayRow, const int arrayElements)
{
int min, min_i, min_j;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRow; i++) {
    min = array[i][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayElements; j++) {
        if (min > array[i][j]) {
            min = array[i][j];
            min_i = i;
            min_j = j;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Лектор сказал, что нужно использовать отдельную функцию для поиска мин. положительного элемента в каждой строке и функция должна возвращать эти значения, чтобы потом можно было бы наполнить новый массив этими значениями из функции. Я застопорился на этом моменте, может ли кто-нибудь помочь или намекнуть как это сделать?

Comment: Ну, а в чём проблема? Напишите функцию, которая будет искать этот самый минимальный положительный элемент, имея указатель на строку таблицы (ну и её длину, наверное). Разделение на мелкие осмысленные функции — правильная техника.

Comment: @VladD Вообще в этом коде я уже вижу функцию, ее осталось только вызвать

Comment: @Mike: Хм, и правда. Это вызывает сразу вопросы об авторстве кода.

Comment: @Mike, да, но ведь функция должна возвратить значения. В данном случае функция должна вернуть 4 мин. пол. числа из 4х строк, честно, я не имею понятия как это сделать.

Comment: @user3638337 Думаю лучше всего, что бы тот кто ее будет вызывать, подготовил массив для возвращаемых значений и передал его как параметр в функцию. Либо функция должна обрабатывать столько информации, что бы вернуть одно значение. Т.е. искать минимум в одной строке массива, а уж хождение по строкам - забота вызывающей ее функции

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, попробую

Comment: @user3638337 А что делать, если в строке все элементы отрицательные и нет минимального положительного элемента?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Программа должна сигнализировать ошибки, если преобразование или заполнение не возможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нет никакой необходимости вызывать функцию поиска минимальных элементов сразу же для всего двумерного массива. Следует функцию вызывать отдельно для каждой строки.

Функция может выглядеть следующим образом

```
int * min_element( int *a, int n )
{
    int *min = a + n;

    for ( int *p = a; p != a + n; ++p )
    {
        if ( *p > 0 && ( min == a + n || *p < *min ) ) min = p;
    }

    return min;
}
```

Функция возвращает указатель на минимальный положительный элемент в одномерном массиве или на конец массива, если такого элемента в массиве нет.

Вызов функции может выглядеть следующим образом

```
for ( int i = 0; i < arrayRow; i++ ) 
{
    int *min = min_element( array[i], arrayElements );

    if ( min == array[i] + arrayElements ) { /* возникла ошибка. делайте, что хотите */ }
    else sqrtArray[i] = std::sqrt( ( double )*min );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Осталось только разобраться в вашей функции :)

Comment: @user3638337 Вначале она устанавливает целевой указатель min на конец строки. Если же в строке присутствуют положительные элементы, то этому целевому указателю присваивается указатель указывающий на текущий положительный элемент. В вызывающей функции проверяется, равен ли указатель, возвращенный из функции концу строки. Если да, то значит не было в массиве положительных элементов. Вы можете протестировать  функцию для любого одномерного массива.